# Error al cargar página web

Tags: php, javascript, netbeans

[image: Imagen del error]

Es lo que pasa cuando quiero probar la página web, lo que se quería lograr es que se mostrara un mensaje de que había un usuario registrado pero solo sale ese error, agradecería a quien ya le haya pasado ese error y me ayudara, ya revisé el código muchas veces y todo esta como en el curso que estoy siguiendo.

config.inc.php

```
$nombre_servidor = 'localhost';
$nombre_usuario = 'root';
$password = '';
$nombre_base_datos = 'blog';
```

Usuario.inc.php

```
<?php

class Usuarios {

    private $id;
    private $nombre;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $fecha_registro;
    private $activo;

    public function __construct($id, $nombre, $email, $password, $fecha_registro, $activo) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->fecha_registro = $fecha_registro;
        $this->activo = $activo;
    }

    public function obtener_id() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function obtener_nombre() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function obtener_password() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function obtener_fecha_registro() {
        return $this->fecha_registro;
    }

    public function esta_activo() {
        return $this->activo;
    }

        public function cambiar_nombre($nombre) {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    public function cambiar_emial($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function cambiar_password($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function cambiar_activo($activo) {
        $this->activo = $activo;
    }

}
```

Conexion.inc.php

```
 <?php

    class Conexion {

    private static $conexion;

    public static function abrir_conexion() {
        if (!isset(self::$conexion)) {
            try {
                include_once 'config.inc.php';

                self::$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$nombre_servidor; dbname=$nombre_base_datos", $nombre_usuario, $password);
                self::$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

            } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                print "ERROR: " .$ex ->getMessage() . "<br>";
                die();
            }
        }
    }

    public static function cerrar_conexion() {
        if (isset(self::$conexion)) {
            self::$conexion = null;
        }
    }

    public static function obtener_conexion() {
        return self::$conexion;
    }
}
```

RepositorioUsuario.inc.php

```
class RepositorioUsuario {

    public static function obtener_todos($conexion) {
        $usuarios = array();

        if (isset($conexion)) {
            try {

                include_once 'Usuario.inc.php';

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";

                $sentencia = $conexion->prepare($sql);
                $sentencia -> execute();
                $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll();

                if (count($resultado)) {
                    foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
                        $usuarios[] = new Usuario(
                                $fila['id'], $fila['nombre'], $fila['email'], $fila['password'], $fila['fecha_registro'], $fila['activo']);
                    }
                } else {
                    print 'No hay usuarios';
                }
            } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                print "ERROR" . $ex->getMessage();
            }
            return $usuarios;
        }
    }
}
```

El index

```
<?php
include_once 'app/Conexion.inc.php';
include_once 'app/RepositorioUsuario.inc.php';

Conexion :: abrir_conexion();
$usuarios = RepositorioUsuario :: obtener_todos(Conexion::obtener_conexion());
echo count($usuarios);
Conexion :: cerrar_conexion();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Easter Eggs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" />
    </head>
    <body>   
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Este botón despliega la barra de navegación</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Easter Eggs</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Entradas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Favoritos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Autores</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <u1 class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Iniciar sesion</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Registro</a></li>
                    </u1>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>,,
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>Easter Eggs</h1>
                <p>
                    Web dedicada a descubrir y compartir los Easter Eggs de los Videojuegos
                </p>
            </div>        
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Busqueda
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Que buscas?">
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="form-control">Buscar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" aria-hidden="true"></span> Filtro
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> Archivo
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ultimas entradas
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Todavia no hay entradas que mostrar</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error consiste en que no encuentra la clase `Usuario`, si te fijas, tienes la clase con el nombre `Usuarios` en `Usuario.inc.php`, cambiale el nombre a `Usuario`